# Guake's global shortcut is intercepted by gnome applications

Tags: gnome, guake, 17.10

I'm trying the ubuntu 17.10 beta2 to evaluate the new gnome experience.

What I found odd is that guake does not work fine: when the focus is on most applications (including `gnome-terminal`, gnome `settings`, OpenOffice, etc) - it (the app) intercepts the guake global shortcut, be it the default <kbd>F12</kbd> or something more exotic like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd>. So the guake does not pop up. But some apps (like Google Chrome) behave well and don't intercept it.

It looks like a bug to me, not sure though what app issue tracker to send it to.

So, can it be fixed with some exotic configuration option, or if it's a bug, what repository do I need to report to? The Gnome's one? Or the guake's?

Comment: Hi,

I have the same problem but no solution.

Comment: @slc66 I provided a reasonable workaround in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround one may unbind the global `F12` (or whatever you have) key in the guake config, then bind it in the gnome native keyboard shortcut configuration: just bind `F12` for the `/usr/bin/guake` command.

The original issue I posted on the gitgub can be found here: https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/1012

Comment: Exact, and You just before have to close Guake to create new shortcut through gnome-control-center.
Thank you very much