# Why does F12 global key doesn't work when focus is on shipped gnome apps in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, guake

When having opened some built-in applications, like "Settings", pressing the F12 key does nothing.

I have it configured to open "[Guake](http://guake-project.org/)" terminal. This is made as a global shortcut in Guake itself. It works when I have focus on other application, for instance Chrome/FF browser etc.

I've checked shortcut settings, but F12 key is not bound to anything.

It did work on previous Ubuntu versions.

It seems that [there is a workaround for it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964953/guakes-global-shortcut-is-intercepted-by-gnome-applications), but anyway it seems broken.

Comment: Would you mind making my answer as accepted?

Comment: See here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1357666/395716

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this issue on the official [Guake github-page](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/492#issuecomment-119075514):

Select `Keyboard` from Ubuntu `Settings`.

At the bottom of the page click on `+` and set a new shortcut:

```
Name: Guake
Command: guake -t
Shortcut: F12
```

**Note:** No reboot is needed after setting the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

> In some reason, guake make mistake in its session data file and this
> can be one of the reasons why gueke suddenly stop to work.

You can try also to remove guake's session data.

just remove this file `~/.config/guake/session.json`

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.config/guake/session.json
```

then just type `guake` in you terminal.