# Guake keyboard shortcuts no longer working

Tags: shortcut-keys, guake

I installed Ubuntu 21.04, and now Guake no longer responds to any keyboard shortcuts.

Toggle full screen appears to work when the window is focused.

Can I check in some config file that the preferences window is indeed setting them correctly? I usually use F1, but any other choice to show the screen no longer responds.

I used `sudo apt autoremove guake`, then reinstalled, but it still has the same problem. Anything I can do?

Comment: Are you sure that guake is running?

Comment: Yes, it is running.

Comment: Toggle fullscreen appears to work when the window is focused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233025/how-to-remove-gnome-shell-from-ubuntu-20-04-lts-to-install-other-desktop-environ)

Comment: Is it necessary to remove the GNOME shell? If I then reinstall another environment, which one is a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Xorg instead of Wayland to fix this (an easy switch via the Ubuntu login screen, look to the bottom right of the screen, or search for how to switch to Xorg).

Wayland is default in Ubuntu 21.04, but not compatible with Guake.

See the guide here: https://www.maketecheasier.com/switch-xorg-wayland-ubuntu1710/

Comment: Well as of Ubuntu 22.04 - Wayland is the default going forward so a more permanent fix would be preferrable.

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 20 / gnome-shell / wayland seems to have (partially?) disabled quake's ability to set global keybindings.

You can manually re-enable them by going into system settings -> devices -> keyboard and scrolling to the bottom and add them by clicking on the + and bind the key to the command line equivalent to do what you want with guake.

The only guake keybinding I've tried changing is the one to open the window.

Comment: This works to open guake, but is quite slow at snapping open the window. Perhaps there is some way of fixing the global keybinding issue?

Answer (score 7):

You can go to the Settings -> Keyboard -> Customize shortcuts -> Custom shortcuts -> Add. With the next command: `guake -t`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tgSI.png)

Answer (score 3):

This is because of an upgrade from xorg to wayland and guake no longer can access global hotkeys. This affects all versions of Ubuntu from 21 onwards.

1. Type `which guake` in terminal. Save the result.
2. Type `which guake-toggle` in terminal. Save the result.
3. Search for 'Startup Applications' and hit 'Add'. Add a new entry for `guake` using the path from `which guake`.
4. Search for 'Keyboard' and hit enter. Go to 'Keyboard Shortcuts' -> 'View and Customize shortcuts'
5. Scroll down to 'Custom Shortcuts'
6. Hit the '+' sign to add a new shortcut
7. Choose your key and under command paste the output from `which guake-toggle`.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer [here](https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/492#issuecomment-532657571). To create a quicker opening shortcut for guake than simply running `guake` via a specially created shortcut, put this in `/usr/bin/guake-toggle.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8; -*-
# Copied from https://github.com/Guake/guake/issues/492#issuecomment-324165795
import dbus

try:
    bus = dbus.SessionBus()
    remote_object = bus.get_object('org.guake3.RemoteControl', '/org/guake3/RemoteControl')
    remote_object.show_hide()
except dbus.DBusException:
    pass
```

then execute it from the setting->keyboard shortcuts. I have ./guake1 as the command, and guake1 is:

```
cd /usr/bin/
./guake-toggle.py
```