# Guake stops working after I lock the screen

Tags: xorg, window, wayland, guake

I solved the [keyboard shortcut problem](https://askubuntu.com/a/1393653/395716)  with Guake by using Xorg instead of Wayland as a Windows display manager.

However, whenever I lock the screen (Ubuntu 23.04), then return, Guake needs to be rebooted with `nohup guake &`, then it works again (and with the dropdown keyboard shortcuts).

What is the reason for this? As a fix, can I auto-run this command on screen unlock? Or something to fix this?